# Substituting Peppers

Tags: substitutions, chili-peppers, spicy-hot

What pepper can be substituted for a habanero when no habaneros are available?

Comment: What is the purpose in using the habanero to begin with?  Any pepper can add flavor or heat ; but if you're looking for one or the other a particular pepper might help get you a better, more accessible answer.  For instance,  the Scotch bonnet @Bob mentioned is the same species but you're not likely to have one available without the other.

Answer (score 7):

Scotch bonnet is very similar, if they're available.

Comment: +1. I'm in the UK. It's really hard to find Habaneros, but Scotch Bonnets are in almost every supermarket. They're sweet, fruity, and oh-god-that-was-a-mistake hot. :)

Answer (score 6):

Very few peppers have both the intense fruitiness and the extreme heat level of a habanero. One option might be to use a combination of dried ancho chilis for their fruitiness, and a fresh hot chili of your choice for the spice level. Thai bird chilis, for example, are quite hot.

Comment: I really enjoy the *flavor* of those things, but the level of *hot* they bring is such an issue...

Answer (score 1):

Another very hot*, fruity pepper is the Bhut Jolokia, but if you don't have habanero where you are you probably don't have ghost peppers either. (Hottest depending on where it's grown)